# Python typing for variable declaration inside __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, typing, typechecking

I'm wondering if this is the correct way to use type checking inside `__init__`. I'm setting these variables to 'empty' as they will be set within other methods. Is that the best practice way when using typing?

Does it make sense for more custom data types like dataframe?

e.g.

```
from collections import Counter
from typing import Dict
import pandas as pd

class Example:

    def __init__(self):
        self.sentence: Dict[str, list] = {}
        self.counter: Counter = Counter()
        self.df: pd.DataFrame = pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: Seems fine, type checking is most useful when you have function arguments

Comment: You’re not doing any type checking here that’s type hinting, also I’d assume you’d have those args in the init declaration itself

Comment: Type hinting (which I assume you meant) is used for function arguments, but your `__init__()` has no arguments (other than `self`).